# "The result that came up" vs "The result came up to"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Do they mean the same or different things?

Example sentence:

> She summed all the numbers. The result **that came up was** 283.

Or:

> She summed all the numbers. The result **came up to** 283.

Would the meaning change in this sentence? If so, in which way?

Comment: I think "*the result came up to*" sounds a little awkward.  The *result* didn't come up to 283, the *numbers* came to 283.

Comment: Where did you get that sentence? Are you writing it?

Comment: @Lambie The first sentence was written by me. The second one from a native English speaker (from England).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your first sentence

> She summed all the numbers.

your second phrases will have the same meaning

> result that came up was
>   the result came up to

Without the first sentence

> result that came up was

describes whatever result occurred, whereas

> the result came up to

"***up to***" implies a *summation* or some sort of *calculation*.

Comment: Came up sounds like a lottery number.

Answer (score 1):

Adding numbers

- The result came to x
- The result came up to x
- The result that came up was x.

They are all right. However, if you are adding numbers yourself in your head or on paper, the first one is the most natural way to say it.

However,

there can be a nuance here.

came **up to** some amount can mean the person was expecting a lower amount.

"Look, Johnny, I added the numbers and they came up to X."

and

**came up** alone, "The result that came up was X." would mean either this was added on a machine or that the person has a different result from yours. In that sense, we also say; came out: the result that came out [of my calculation] was x.

Please note: though we say to find the sum of numbers, etc. I prefer to use add numbers in everyday speech. To sum numbers sounds like Excel, to my ears. It is,therefore, logical to say: the sum came out x; the sum came out as x.